# Statistical method for estimation of Penetrance

Tags: estimation, likelihood, biostatistics, genetics

I was thinking on a problem: there is a rare disease, associated with some ultra-rare genomic variant (which means ~ 1 out of millions), and there are estimations of penetrance (how many individuals with such variant will develop the disease).

Since the variant is ultra-rare, we do not have reliable estimations of the frequency of such variants in the general population (so far).

How do we estimate penetrance: we take individuals, who has this disease, we find out who has this variant among the individuals with the disease, we estimate penetrance based on the relatives of the individual who also have this variant but have or have not developed the disease. However, we totally miss families that have this variant, but don't have the disease. Thus, we overestimate the penetrance since we pre-select individuals who already have a disease and their families.

In medical literature for one particular disease I've seen the words "Using modern likelihood methods, we find out the true penetrance which is X,95%CI:Y-Z". What are these modern likelihood methods? There were no reference to the methods used ...

Comment: You could start with this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=likelihood+methods+for+estimation+of+penetrance&oq=likelihood+methods+for+estimation+of+penetrance&aqs=chrome..69i57.13432j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Perhaps you could post the paper you are referring to, OP. Often, medical literature has great inaccuracies and misinterpretations due to physicians operating without any qualified statistical support. This makes it even harder to know what the authors meant without the paper.

Comment: It was a short period of mental disability for me. I thought that the request is too complex for Google. The first comment totally answers the question.